# Xml NFSe (NotaBlu)

Tags: c#, web-service, xml, nfe

Olá, estou tendo problemas para achar uma documentação decente para fazer integração com o `WebService` da `notablu`, preciso de pelo menos um modelo de como seria um XML pra enviar (de preferência com legenda do que alguns valores significam, ou coisas como eu poderia pegar valores de assinatura, certificado etc... caso precise), mas o principal seria o modelo mesmo, os que eu achei são de 2015 2014 pra baixo.

Estou fazendo com `C#` usando o mantra do M. V. C. com EF

Comment: Apesar do título `NFe` creio que deve está falando de `NFSe`, realmente a documentação é fraca e não padronizada. Recomendo entrar em contato direto com o provedor do serviço ou `fazer na raça` pelo `webservice`.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow , vou ver se consigo algo com ele, te informo na sequência